# for loop in asp.net

Tags: c#

HI,

I have a for loop

```
for(int i=0;i<=1000;i++)
{

}
```

I want to stop the for loop for an particular value like i=100 without applying break point.
so how can we achieve it?

Comment: Why don't you want to use break; ?

Comment: Why is that without break? I want you to stop doing that algo but you cant stop typing the code? Is this what you mean?

Comment: What are you mean under "stop the for loop"? Do you intend to exit out of loop or just debug break?

Answer (score 3):

```
if(i==100) break; // exits the loop
```

Or

```
if(i==100 && Debugger.IsAttached)
    Debugger.Break(); // pauses the IDE
```

Comment: I like the whole Debugger thing, never knew about that.  Is that VS2010 feature only?

Comment: @Chuck - no, I think that goes way back

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Debugger.Break()` in conjunction with `Debugger.IsAttached`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with using breakpoint.

Right-click on breakpoint and click `condition`. Set your conditions there.

Refer to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sye83ce.aspx) for further info. :D

Comment: This applies a breakpoint. The asker specifically requested a solution that does *not* involve breakpoints.

Comment: The problem with conditional breakpoints is that they are **dead slow**.